# Difference between live() and bind() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form and a button which is not a `submit` within the form.
I use jQuery to validate the form before submit.

I first have:

```
$('#btadd').live('click', function() {
  $('#formadd').submit();
  //return; //it doesn't matter
});
$('#formadd').submit(function() {
  if (...) {
    alert('incompleted!');
    return false;
  } else if (...) {
    alert('invalid!');
    return false;
  } else
    return true;
});
```

The problem is if the form is not completed, when I click button, the popup ('incompleted!') will occur **twice**.

Then I try to replace `live` with `bind`, then it works fine.

I have searched for the difference between `live()` and `bind()`, but still don't know how they work in this example. My code works as what I want now, but I want to figure out what happen here. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Can you please fill in the conditions in the `if/else-if`?

Comment: Have you read their respective docs pages?

Comment: Why do you need both functions?  Why not put the submit function inside the bind function?

Comment: `live` will also bind the event to 'future' (i.e., newly created on the fly) buttons. But they need to have the same class - you are using an id selector, so it'll conflict, IMO. Change `#btadd` to `.btadd` and use it as a class for the button and it should work fine I guess. (Bind will only do so for existing ones)

Comment: I have checked the docs, but still confused how they work in this example. I use a separate button div because it is easy for me to style it.

Comment: @Nupul I have changed to class, but it is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

live works for any element added to the DOM with that selector in contrast to bind that only works with elements already in the DOM.  Let's say you have an element `<div id="test">Test</div>`.  If that element exists at the time the bind method is called then the bind will work as expected.  If instead the element does not exist then it will not work.

This is in contrast with live that works with any element with the selector no matter when it is added to the DOM.

Comment: I know this. But why they perform differently in my case?